# execute script B whenever script A is terminated with CTRL C

Tags: linux, bash

so I have this code that use the GPIO and before it start it turns on the LED so we know the the script was triggered and that something abnormal was going on.

```
echo "17" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/direction
echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value
```

the problem is that sometimes people will press "ctrl c" and exit of the script without resetting the GPIO

I was wondering of there is some whay to trigger some lines of code to do certin things whenever the code is killed with `CTRL C`

Comment: Yes.  Set a trap for SIGINT.  eg `trap 'echo do some cleanup' SIGINT`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BASH - using trap ctrl+c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771909/bash-using-trap-ctrlc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to perform some cleanup, set a trap.  For this case, it sounds like you want to `echo 1` to gpio17/value when the script exits:

```
trap 'echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value' 0
```

This will execute the command no matter how the script exits.  (Unless the script gets a SIGKILL.  Nothing you can do about that.)

Comment: does it matter where this line goes? can I just put it at the end of my script? thanks

Comment: If you're mostly worried about SIGINT, it just needs to be executed before the user hits `ctrl-C`.  If it is not executed before the script exits, the trap is not set and the `echo` won't be executed.

Comment: Note that usually you want to set a trap right before you change whatever needs to be cleaned up. For example: `trap 'test -n "$tmpfile" && rm -f "$tmpfile"' 0; tmpfile="$(mktemp)";` is appropriate, but `tmpfile="$(mktemp)"; trap 'rm "$tmpfile"' 0;` is wrong because there's a race condition in which the file will not be removed. (eg,  mktemp is executed, but SIGINT received before the trap is set).